# Composite primary keys or surrogates when dealing with date/time

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I've seen a lot of discussion regarding this. I'm just seeking for your suggestions regarding this. Basically, what I'm using is PHP and MySQL. I have a `users` table which goes:

```
         users
------------------------------
uid(pk) | username | password
------------------------------
   12   |  user1   | hashedpw
------------------------------
```

and another table which stores updates by the user

```
                updates
--------------------------------------------
uid |        date         |     content
--------------------------------------------
 12 | 2011-11-17 08:21:01 | updated profile
 12 | 2011-11-17 11:42:01 | created group
--------------------------------------------
```

The user's profile page will show the 5 most recent updates of a user. The questions are:

1. For the `updates` table, would it be possible to set both ***uid*** and ***date*** as composite primary keys with ***uid*** referencing ***uid*** from `users`
2. OR would it be better to just create another column in `updates` which auto-increments and will be used as the primary key (while uid will be FK to uid in `users`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea (under 1.) rests on the assumption that a user can *never* do two "updates" within one second. That is very poor design. You never know what functions you will implement in the future, but chances are that some day 1 click leads to 2 actions and therefore 2 lines in this table.

I say "updates" quoted because I see this more as a logging table. And who knows what you may want to log somewhere in the future.

As for unusual primary keys: don't do it, it almost always comes right back in your face and you have to do a lot of work to add a proper autoincremented key afterwards.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I guess I was thinking too "humanly". What's a good way to set the table up though? Any suggestions?

Comment: `logid / uid / ts / eventtype / details` where `logid` is PK autoincrement, `ts` is a timestamp column, `eventtype` is freeform but short (varchar 16 chars), `details` is freeform and not too long (varchar 1024). Splitting events in type+details makes that you can easily filter on "all logins", "all new groups", etc.

Comment: ps. of course you could make `eventtype` an `ENUM`, but logging is generally a good thing to do so you don't want to make it hard for yourself to add a new kind of event. And the content of `details` shouldn't be that long in daily use.

Comment: @MikeSanchez pps. in web based environments, having an `ip` column for the remote address is also very convenient at times.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and making me think towards the future. My app won't be using those for now but will definitely be of some use pretty soon. I guess that's the proper way to build.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the requirement but a third possibility is that you could make the key (uid, date, content). You could still add a surrogate key as well but in that case you would presumably want to implement *both* keys - a composite and a surrogate - not just one. Don't make the mistake of thinking you have to make an either/or choice.

Whether it is useful to add the surrogate or not depends on how it's being used - don't add a surrogate unless or until you need it. In any case uid I would assume to be a foreign key referencing the users table.